# Why does the cursor keep jumping to the end of my TextFieldView while typing?

Tags: javascript, binding, sproutcore

I have a sproutcore 1.0 page with SC.ListView items and a SC.TextFieldView bound to the same property of a model.

When I type at the end of the TextFieldView everything works as expected. If I position the cursor in the middle and start typing the cursor jumps to the end. What could be causing this?

I *suspect* that the jumping is happening when the updated value is propagated via the bindings. If I type quickly I can enter a few characters before the cursor jumps.

Comment: Apparently this is a bug. The SproutCore documentation is in a sorry state at the moment so discussing this is difficult. At some point in the future the SproutCore folks are releasing their own site for discussing all things related to it so there wont be responses here. In the mean time I'll close this question since there's obviously not going to be any useful help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in SproutCore 1.4 or higher. If not, try setting applyImmediately to NO in your TextFieldView instances in SproutCore 1.4 or higher.